# Same holding register address for different purposes in Modbus?

Tags: modbus

I have a device which is supposed to support the Modbus protocol. By Function-3, I can read an input status at address-1000, but the same address-1000 is used as an output so I can write the value to the output by Function-6.

So when I write to holding register 1000 I can't read it back, because it is addressed to an input. Is that valid in the Modbus protocol, or could it be that the device is not supporting standard Modbus and has its own Modbus-like, customized protocol?

Comment: You can refer to the Modbus specs, but offhand, what you describe is not unreasonable. Whether it is ‘correct’ is of little consequence - if that is how the device is documented to operate, then that is how it operates.

Comment: What do you get reading with function 4?